# Data-binding does not return the needed values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

Hi I am just cratching the surface in learning knockout.js and basicly programming on the client side.I am using web api on the server to send some data to the client.This is the model from the server:

```
 public IEnumerable<POC_GetUpcomingLessons_Result> UpcomingLessons { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<POC_GetUpcomingExams_Result> UpcomingExams { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<POC_StudentTasks> ToDoList { get; set; }
```

Now I am sure that the data reaches the client because I tryed debugging the code and I get back an object that has the needed data.This is the code I am making on the client-side:

```
var dashboardObservableCollection = ko.observableArray();
    var isInitialized = false;

    var vm = {
        dashboard: dashboardObservableCollection,

        //operations
        refreshData: refreshData,      
        activate: activate
    };
    console.log("I got here");
    return vm;

    function activate() {
        logger.log("Dashboard View Activated", null, 'dashboard', true);
        if (!isInitialized) {
            isInitialized = true;
            ...
            return fetchModulesData();
        }
    }

    function fetchModulesData() {
        return dataService.getDashboard(1200528)
            .then(fetchModulesCompleted)
            .fail(fetchDataFailed);

        function fetchModulesCompleted(data) {
            dashboardObservableCollection(data.ToDoList);
            debugger;
            vm.dataLoading(false);
        }
```

Data here gets back all three IEnumerables I chose to only get the ToDoList for the moment.

This is the view:

```
<ul class='to-do' data-bind="foreach: dashboard">
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'dashboard/toDoList'} -->
            <!--/ko-->
</ul>

<li>Fill in initial evaluation
     <ul>
         <li class="course icon" data-bind="text : ModuleName"></li>
         <li class="courses icon">
               <a href="#" data-bind="text : CourseName"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="teacher icon" data-bind="text: TeacherName"></li>
     </ul>
```

I am not sure where I am making the mistake but the data gets to the client , I just can not seem to make it display on the view.It does not even get into the foreach.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly since much of the code is missing, but some questions spring to mind: a) have you called ko.applyBindings()? b) the *compose* binding is not (to my knowledge) part of the core, so i assume it's some plugin - have you already tried using "simple" bindings to see if the foreach is being fetched?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?
You should post the contents of the dashboard/toDoList view and also the rendered html to help us troubleshoot.

Comment: @Grim compose is a custom binding that is part of the durandal SPA framework.